# Convert timezone shift in seconds from UTC in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am giving a call to an weather API which returns me an JSON containing timezone -25000 and in the docs it is mentioned as "timezone: Shift in seconds from UTC" I want to convert this in actual date and time by using JavaScript.

```
   {
      "timezone": -25200,
      "id": 420006353,
      "name": "Mountain View",
      "cod": 200
   }
```

Please tell me how to convert this "timezone:-25200" in actual time.

Comment: Have you made your own effort? `25200` is -7 hours, you could make your own mapping?

Comment: can you please tell me how can I make my own mapping?

Comment: It will be a function which takes in a number and returns the timezone offset in whatever value you want. Use an object. I wouldn't recommend a calculation. Instead work it out by hand and put the values in yourself.

Comment: @evolutionbox see, I don't know what is this -25200, nor I know what calculations are needed to convert this entity into actual date, can you please give me any clue (like convert Km into meters, convert unix timestamp into actual time) likewise?

Comment: Timezones are not dates. They are time offsets. 25200 is the number of seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert timezone in seconds to actual date like following

```
  var d = new Date((new Date().getTime())-25200*1000)
  d.toISOString()
  ""2020-12-26T13:50:09.012Z""
```

Comment: `getTime()` is in ***ms***. Please explain logic of subtracting a value in seconds from one in ms

Comment: I did it but giving error "TypeError: (new Date()).getTime() is not a function"
I put the code like this - 
const dateBuilder = () => {
        var d = new Date((new Date().getTime())(timezone)*1000)
        //d.toISOString();
        return d.toISOString();
    }

return(<p><em class="white-text">{dateBuilder()}</em></p>);

Comment: @Siddhesh you didn’t copy the example exactly

Comment: Okay, I made a small mistake giving me error, but I have fixed it now.
but A time offset is an amount of time subtracted from or added to Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) time to get the current civil time. In the above code I can see the value is subtracted from system time. how does it works exactly?
Please explain @evolutionbox and Narendra kumawat

Comment: @Siddhesh I don't understand. You just explained how it works

Comment: @evolutionxbox I got it, I used my own code to get local time through UTC.

Comment: it gives me incorrect time. @Siddhesh if possible share your solution